# Infinite loop using triple nested for loop (32-bit Assembly)

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, 32-bit

The C++ code below I am trying to implement in 32-bit assembly is written as so:

```
for(int ebx = 3; ebx < 10; ebx++){
      print("LO");
      for(int esi = 2; esi < ebx; esi++){
           PRINT("L1");
           for(int ebp = 0; ebp < esi; ebp++){
                PRINT("L2");
           }
      }
}
```

This is my assembly code:

```
SECTION .data                    ; Section containing initialized data
helloWorld0: dw "L1",10,0
helloWorld1: dw "L2",10,0
helloWorld2: dw "L3",10,0

SECTION .bss                     ; Section containing uninitialized data
SECTION .text                    ; Section containing code
extern printf                    ; Print function from glibc
global main                      ; Linker needs this to find the entry point
main:
nop                              ; This no-op keeps gdb happy
push     ebp                     ; Set up stack frame for debugger
mov      ebp,esp
push     ebx                     ; Must preserve EBP, EBX, ESI & EDI
push     esi
push     edi
; Everything before this is boilerplate; use it for all  apps

mov ebx, 3                      ;L1
mov esi, 2                      ;L2
mov ebp, 0                      ;L3
L1:
push    helloWorld0
call    printf

L2:
push    helloWorld1
call    printf

L3:
push    helloWorld2
call    printf
inc     ebp
cmp     ebp, esi
jne     L3

inc     esi
cmp     esi, ebx
jne     L2

mov     esi, 2
inc     ebx
cmp     ebx, 10
jne     L1
; Everything after this is boilerplate; use it for all apps
pop     edi                     ; Restore saved registers
pop     esi
pop     ebx
mov     esp,ebp                 ; Destroy stack frame before returning
pop     ebp
ret                              ; Return control to Linux
```

It seems that the code never determines when ebp = esi. I am new to assembly language, so my professor has provided boilerplates. I used EBP, ESI, and EBX as they are preserved for use. Any ideas on what is causing the infinite loop on the third nested loop?

Comment: What did you find out when debugging line by line inside the loop?

Comment: I am using linux terminal to code, what software is needed to debug?

Comment: Seems you have a similar assignment to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39680843/infinite-loop-on-simple-assembly-loop . Some of my comments there would apply here.

Comment: Use gdb to debug in a Linux text shell, just like Michael suggested in comments on your previous question.  See the bottom of the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for some tips on using it for asm.

Comment: @Michael Petch, hey, thanks for your help on my previous question! It has brought me to this point of my program!

Comment: I can see the problem.  Single-step through your loop in gdb, and look at EBP the second time your code enters the inner-most loop.

Answer (score 2):

In your C, `int ebp = 0` is inside both outer loops, and runs before entering the inner loop *every* time.  That's not where it is in your asm.

Also, don't modify EBP inside your function.  Your prof's boilerplate makes a "stack frame" (google it), using EBP as the frame pointer.  At the end of the function, `mov  esp,ebp` is used to clean up.  (good thing, too, since your code pushes args for printf but doesn't ever adjust ESP after printf returns!)

Presumably a future lecture will talk about accessing function args and locals using `[ebp + 8]` or `[ebp - 4]` or whatever.  For now, just know that this frame-pointer nonsense is wasting another one of your precious registers, so you can't use it.  (i.e. the only 3 registers of the 8 x86 integer regs that you can use and that aren't modified by function calls are EDI, ESI, and EBX.)

---

re: Cedric's point about the branch condition:

Your loops are fine, unless I missed something.

Your loops all have the convenient property that they should always run once, so you can write them as `do{}while()` loops without an extra check at the top.  This means they can be implemented nicely in asm, with the check at the bottom like you're doing.

So for example, printf (i.e. the loop body) should run twice on the first inner loop: once with EBP=0, and once with EBP=1.  After that, the increment will make EBP=2, so the CMP/JNE will fall through because EBP==ESI==2.

For the outer loops, the logic is the same.  The whole inner loop is the "loop body", and it runs before you increment the counter.  So you're fine.

You could equivalently use CMP/JL to do a signed comparison and re-run the loop body while the counter is less than the limit.  That would match the C.  It would also have changed the failure mode from approx. 2^32 trips through the inner loop (until `inc ebp` wrapped around and reached 2).  With JL, the failure mode from your current bug would be to only take one trip through the inner loop if the loop counter was so high that we shouldn't have entered the loop in the first place.

---

Normally in asm, it's easier to count down to zero, e.g. `dec ebp / jnz` doesn't need a CMP.  Transforming your loops to do that is non-trivial because your outer loop counters act as upper-bounds for the inner loops.  It should be possible, though.  You're not printing out the counter values inside the loop, so it doesn't actually matter what they are, just the loop trip counts.

Comment: This is definitely the answer, although a `for` loop has certain properties that are not kept in your answer. I know that setting optimisation to high settings in your compiler might rewrite it as you said, translating C to asm directly requires that a `for` loop might not run at all, if the comparison returns false. Moreover, the increment is done after the loop body. Finally, using `jne`instead of `jl` is confusing, because as far as I know, there is no benefit in doing so, apart from unexpected behaviour if someone without knowledge in asm tries to use your code for another projet.

Comment: @Cedric: The increments here *are* done after the loop bodies, as I pointed out in my answer.  The counter values in registers during loop execution in the OP's code *do* match the C.

Comment: @Cedric: The normal way to implement a `for()` loop in asm is with a test&branch outside the loop to check if it needs to run 0 times, then to fall into a `do(){}while` structure with the test&branch at the bottom, like the OP has.  As I pointed out in the answer, leaving out the initial test outside the loop is possible because of the special case of the OP's code.  As far as JNE vs. JL, yes, I agree, it's generally better to narrow the range of true comparisons when it's convenient and doesn't interfere with macro-fusion (of cmp/jcc into a single uop) on Intel CPUs.

Comment: Yes, but the comparison is done after the loop body and after the increment. Which means, as you said, that it is closer to a do-while than a for. Even though the result might be the same, the way it is done is different. In this case, if OP had tried replicating as much as possible the initial C code, debugging would have been quite easier, even without a debugger. For example, the `jl` instruction would have prevented the infinite loop from happening.